# Bootstrap: Utilize Media Query for Custom Responsive Class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to make a custom class via bootstrap that does the following:

- When the screen size is `xs`: then make the text left justified.

Here is what I have:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .text-left-xs{
    @extend .text-left;
  }
}
```

However when I run it: here is the error I get:

> You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
>   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.text-left-xs {
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
  text-align: left;
 }
}
```